# Object stored with SharedObject have own default properties? Can it be remove?

Tags: actionscript-3, shared-objects

I have a Object with some data define by me, and I use SharedObject to store it in the computer. When I view the .sol file with FlashDevelop SharedObject Reader, I notice the object info have some data which is not defined by me. Among them are:

> soundTransform (object), buttonMode, hitArea, useHandCursor, tabChildren, mouseChildren, needSoftKeyboard,focusRect etc.

Are these data removable so that I could maybe possibly reduce the size of the .sol file?

Comment: Looks like you're storing a DisplayObject there.

Answer (score 1):

Might be best to create your own object that you save, and then reconstruct the object from those properties when loading. Eg;

```
var myobj:Object = {x:theClip.x, y:theClip.y, ..., ...};
```